# Did the Prophet (SAW) say "he should treat the people the way he would love to be treated"?

Tags: hadith

Did the Prophet (SAW) say "he should treat the people the way he would love to be treated"?

Is the hadith authentic?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider to take some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is part of a larger hadith in the Ṣaḥīḥ collection of Muslim ibn al-Hajjaj,

> مَنْ أَحَبَّ أَنْ يُزَحْزَحَ عَنْ النَّارِ وَيَدْخُلَ الْجَنَّةَ فَلْتُدْرِكْهُ مَنِيَّتُهُ وَهُوَ يُؤْمِنُ بِاللَّهِ وَالْيَوْمِ الْآخِرِ وَيَأْتِي إِلَى النَّاسِ مَا يُحِبُّ أَنْ يُؤْتَى إِلَيْهِ
>
> Whoever would love to be delivered from the Hellfire and entered into Paradise, then let him die with faith in God and the Last Day, and let him treat the people the way he would love to be treated.
>
> [Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 1844](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/74)

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed he has said so. One of the strongest statements is the hadith which is in almost all sunni hadith collections:

> None amongst you believes (truly) **until he loves for his brother**" - or he said "for his neighbour" - "**that which he loves for himself**."
> (This is the wording of sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/77), other versions are in sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/6), Jami' [at-Tirmdihi](https://sunnah.com/urn/727000), sunan [an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/47/55), sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1300680), sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/78))

This hadith says that it is a sign of Iman. Note that [an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/47/33) has also quoted the hadith with the addition ("of goodness").

There's an other similar narration which is in sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1315010) and Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/729490), both on the authority of Ali ibn Abi Talib which says that it is a duty for a Muslim towards his Muslim brothers:

> "There are six courtesies due from a Muslim to another Muslim: To give Salam to him when he meets him, to accept his invitation when he invites him, to reply to him when he sneezes, to visit him when he is ill, to follow his funeral when he dies, **and to love for him what he loves for himself**."

For some reasons on sunnah.com the version of at_Tirmdihi has been qualified as da'if even if both the content and the narrator chains are the same!

And in [Riyad as-Salihin](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1566) you may find this quote from sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/74):

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "He who desires to be rescued from the fire of Hell and to enter Jannah, should die in a state of complete belief in Allah and the Last Day, and **should do unto others what he wishes to be done unto him**."

Which is part of a longer hadith which is also in sunan [ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/31) and [an-Nasa'i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/39/43).

Comment: try to add arabic translation ( origin  ) it make it easy to understand clearly !!
visiting links is hard for readers than adding texts in answer :)

Comment: @MustaphaElbazi the official language of the site is English I only quote Arabic texts in case I need to translate,s o that the reader would have a chance to compare. Else I don't see a necessity to waste space for posting an Arabic text which I've linked as long as there's no possibility to shorten the posts by something like spoilers see meta discussion http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/would-it-be-possible-to-have-spoilers

Comment: for me arabic text is important , and i think this is important ... ! 
why because the majority of translation is't just an understanding of the writer :)